# Any ideas on hiding a TV in a coffee table?

Tags: furniture, television

With 1080p and now 4k Tvs its a waste of technology to watch it from 14'+ away.  Sitting under   6' way from a 50+ inch HDTV is the only way to enjoy all the pixels.
The only way I can think to have a TV that close to the sofa is to have it in the coffee table.
Ideally I would like it to lift out of the top of the table but the screen is too high for a coffee table and I really dont want to cut a hole in the floor. Other option is to hinge the top of the table and mount it on the bottom. Use 2 actuators to help lift.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to mount it or about anything else.

Comment: why would you need to enjoy all the pixels?

Comment: There are lift mechanisms out there, but to get a screen size in under the height of a coffee table is a really tall order. The HD or 1080 is a waste on screens smaller than 32", the pixels are already small enough to get  a great picture on that size screen. It is only marketing hype. Picture this, a beautiful picture on a 64" LED tv at 1080p OR 1080i, you can have the exact same beautiful picture at 720p or 720i. This is what I have read on the tech sites about setting up home theaters and the like. What is the size of tv you were thinking?

Comment: Wait for the long-discussed flexible [roll-up TV](https://www.google.com/search?q=roll-up+tv) screens to make it into production?

Comment: "is the only way to enjoy all the pixels" = perhaps...but can you enjoy the actual movie like that? :)

Comment: Toshiba lists a recommended viewing distance for different screen sizes [here](http://www.toshiba.com/us/recommended-tv-viewing-distance). Some companies also make [under-the-bed TV lifts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTRACAivf7M), but they might unbalance a coffee table. (I have no affiliation with any of the above companies I mentioned.)

Comment: What about putting rollers on the couch and rolling it near the TV when viewing? Just brainstorming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tvtracksystems.com/

We have a couple of TV tracks in my Boston office.  I would suggest that to you.  You can have your insanely close viewing and when people come over you can scoot it back.  Plus it is cool.

Comment: I like but $5k. I wonder if I can make it myself.

Comment: @JustinK - def a DIY idea.  I would ask it as a different question.  It doesn't need to be remote because how much do you move your tv.  I thinka  really good ball bearing and track would do it.  I'm sure there are others better with metal than me that would have ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?
http://www.justlaine.com/2011/01/17365.html

[image]

It wouldn't be too difficult to make.  For a 50" TV, you'll have to build a big one.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

1. Move the couch closer to the TV.
2. Get an 80 inch TV (or projection TV).
3. Mount the TV to the ceiling with a system of counterweights that extend into the attic.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the TV flat, face up under a glass top coffee table.